# React/Redux quiz component loops through incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a React/Redux Quiz application that has 3 main components -  instructions, story and quiz (about the story). When it moves to the quiz component, I'm finding that it's rendering only the alternate (even) questions, but I need it to render  each question in the loop.   Here's the Quiz component -:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { chunk, now } from '../utils'
class Quiz extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      answers: new Array(this.props.question).fill('e'),
      chosenAnswers: []
    }
  }

  onAnswerSelected() {
    let answers = [this.state.answers]
    answers[this.id] = String.fromCharCode(97 + this.i)
    this.setState({ ...this.state,answers })

  }

  render() {
    const { set, enterAnswers, timed, questions } = this.props
    console.log(questions);
    const { text, answers, id } = questions

    return (
      <div>
          <div key={id}>
            <h4>{text}</h4>
            {answers.map((a, i) => (
              <label key={i} style={{ display: 'block' }}>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={`${a.answer}_${i}`}
                  checked={
                    this.state.answers[i] === String.fromCharCode(97 + i)
                  }
                  onChange={this.onAnswerSelected.bind(this)}
                  value={String.fromCharCode(97 + i)}
                />
                <div>{a.answer}. {a.text}</div>
              </label>
            ))}
          </div>
        <div
          className="button"
          onClick={() => enterAnswers(id, this.state.selected, now())}
          style={{
            border: '1px solid black',
            backgroundColor: 'purple',
            display: 'inline-block',
            color: 'white',
            padding: 10
          }}
        >
          Save answers
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Quiz.propTypes = {
  set: PropTypes.array,
  enterAnswers: PropTypes.func,
  id: PropTypes.number,
  timed: PropTypes.number
}

export default Quiz
```

I also need it to loop through and render a complete sets of 4 questions before moving on to the next set of instructions. At the moment, it renders only one question (question 2 but should be 1), then unmounts to the next instructions. Then when the second story component is finished, the Quiz component reverts to question 4 in the first set (because it's incorrectly counting by 2's). What I need it to do is render instructions, then story, then set of 4 questions, then back to instructions again. I hope this is enough details - I can give more if needed!

Not sure if this helps with the second part, but here's also the container component that renders all 3 main components -:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import { enterAnswersMaybeSave, confirmInstructions, confirmStory, moveOn, saveQuiz } from '../actions'
import StoryFeed from '../components/StoryFeed'
import Quiz from '../components/Quiz'
import Instructions from '../components/Instructions'
import { chunk, now } from '../utils'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      errorMessage,
      questions,
      enterAnswersMaybeSave,
      showInstructions,
      confirmInstructions,
      currentStory,
      confirmStory,
      type,
      timed
    } = this.props

    if (!currentStory) {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>
            The task is now complete. Thank-you for your time.{' '}
            <a href={window.wordpress.home}>Back to your dashboard</a>.
          </p>
          {errorMessage.length > 0 && <p>{errorMessage}</p>}
        </div>
      )
    }

    return (
      <div className="instructions">
        {showInstructions && (
          <Instructions
            currentStory={currentStory}
            //after the user has seen the instructions this action creator is called
            confirmInstructions={() => confirmInstructions(currentStory)}
          />
        )}
        {!showInstructions &&
          type == 'story' && (
            <StoryFeed
              id={currentStory}
              timed={timed}
              confirmStory={() => confirmStory(currentStory, now())}
            />
          )}
        {!showInstructions &&
          type == 'quiz' && (
            <Quiz
              questions={questions}
              id={currentStory}
              timed={timed}
              enterAnswers={enterAnswersMaybeSave}
            />
          )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

App.propTypes = {

  enterAnswersMaybeSave: PropTypes.func,
  showInstructions: PropTypes.bool,
  confirmInstructions: PropTypes.func,
  currentStory: PropTypes.number,
  type: PropTypes.string, // TODO: enum this
  timed: PropTypes.number, // TODO: or undefined
  errorMessage: PropTypes.string,
  submit: PropTypes.func
}

const getCurrent = state => state.testMeta.find(t => t.id == state.currentStory)
const getNextQuestion = sets => sets.find(s => !s.completed)
export default connect(
  state => ({
    questions: getNextQuestion(state.sets),
    showInstructions: state.currentStory && !getCurrent(state).instructions,
    currentStory: state.currentStory,
    type: state.currentStory && getCurrent(state).type,
    timed: state.currentStory && getCurrent(state).timed,
    errorMessage: state.errorMessage
  }),
  dispatch =>
    bindActionCreators(
      {
        enterAnswersMaybeSave,
        confirmInstructions,
        confirmStory,
        moveOn,
        saveQuiz
      },
      dispatch
    )
)(App)
```

Comment: Should the quiz component render all questions, or only one question at a time? Please use correct singular/plural words. For example you have "questions: getNextQuestion(state.sets)", does it return multiple questions, or only one question?

Comment: Hi, it should render only one question at a time.

Comment: Then why does it use questions instead of question property? const { text, answers, id } = questions